# How can i make elements to be inline in col class in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have this layout

```
<div class="container-fluid header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>Date From</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="dateFrom" [minDate]="currentDate">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

after that the label is on top of the input. I can't find a way so in this same col-md-4, the label to be
next to the input - inline. So they show together in the same line.

How can i make this and to preserve the responsivness of the col bootstrap class ?

Comment: Seems to work for me - have you any CSS? Maybe `float:left` is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

**Add form tag with inline class.**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <form class="form-inline">

    <div class="col-md-4 form-group ">
        <label>Date From</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="dateFrom" [minDate]="currentDate">
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```